# Unit testing APIGatewayProxyFunction API Controller methods (C# inheritance problem maybe?)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have an ASP.NET Core web API application that's set up as an AWS Serverless lambda function with API Gateway.

I'm working with an instance of `APIGatewayProxyFunction` and I'm trying to unit test some of my controller behavior by injecting `NSubstitute` versions of my database repo.

Now, of course I can instantiate my controller directly and inject the mocked dependencies, but using the auto-gen'd `LambdaEntryPoint` class and taking advantage of the host builder logic lets me get all the MVC routing goodies and I can test actual HTTP method matching and route matching.

My problem is, `builder.UseStartup<Startup>()` uses my real DI service registration code.  I was hoping I could override this behavior and register a mocked instance of my database repo class.

There doesn't seem to be a way to get at the ServiceCollection in the unit test once the object is constructed, so I thought I'd just sub-class the `LambdaEntryPoint` and override the `Init()` function to supply a subclass of `Startup` `MockStartup` instead which registers mocked instances.

The problem it seems is that `Init()` actually gets called during the constructor chain, so I can't really feed mocked instances into my subclass to be used during the `Init()` override.

Super pared down example:

```
var myClass = new ChildClass(7);


public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class constructing");
        Init();
    }

    public virtual void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base class init");
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    private readonly int? _mockedService;

    public ChildClass(int mockedService)
    {
        _mockedService = mockedService;
        Console.WriteLine("Child class constructed");
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Child class init with mocked service {_mockedService}");
    }
}
```

This, of course does not work, because `_mockedService` is still null when we get to executing the overridden `Init()` function.

So, I'm looking for guidance on how I can write a unit test which can submit actual JSON posts to prove MVC routes and HTTP methods for my application while still providing a mocked instance of my database interface?

I'm open to all options, but if possible, I'd like to do this without spinning up a full http webservice and *actually* submitting http requests, but if that's the only option, guidance on the best way to do that with substitutes would be appreciated as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an option to call `Init()` a second time from within `ChildClass.ctor`?

Comment: If only, the IWebHostBuilder instance which is sent into the Init() function isn't accessible in my child class, it's constructed during the method chain of the base class `APIGatewayProxyFunction`, which I don't own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a static Dictionary and `GetHashCode()` to uniquely identify each `LambdaEntryPoint` object created by different tests.

```
public class TestEntryPoint : LambdaEntryPoint
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, IDbRepository> Repos = new();
    
    public IDbRepository Repository => Repos[GetHashCode()];

    protected override void Init(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup(context =>
        {
            var repo = Substitute.For<IDbRepository>();
            Repos[GetHashCode()] = repo;
            var startup = new MockStartup(context.Configuration, repo);
            
            return startup;
        });
    }
}
```

```
public class MockStartup : Startup
{
    private readonly IDbRepository _repository;
    
    public MockStartup(IConfiguration configuration, IDbRepository repository) : base(configuration)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public override void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services
            .AddTransient<IServiceConfiguration, LambdaServiceConfiguration>()
            .AddTransient(_ => _repository);
    }
}
```

This allows my tests to do:

```
var lambdaFunction = new TestEntryPoint();
lambdaFunction.Repository.Whatever(...).Returns(...);
```

using `lambdaFunction.Repository` as my mock